# Restating the following domains

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently struggling with understanding the restatement of the domain:

$0 \leq x^2 \leq 2$ is equivalent to $ |x| \leq \sqrt2$ (why not $ 0 \leq |x| \leq \sqrt2$)?

and

$0 < x^2 < 2$ is equivalent to $0 < |x| < \sqrt2$

How does the restatement of the domain work? I don't understand

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

Comment: "equivalent", not "equal". Statements are not quantities and thus can **NOT** be "equal".

Comment: $0\le |x|$ goes without saying.  It is never not true.  ...However, if $x is real then $0\le x^2$ also goes without saying, so you have a point.  But $x^2\le 2\iff 0\le x^2\le 2\iff |x|\le 2\iff 0\le |x|\le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

$|x|$ cannot be less than zero, so to say $0 \le |x| \le \sqrt2$ is to say $|x| \le \sqrt2$.

Then, of course, we have $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$, so if $x^2 < 2$, then $\sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt2$, and $|x| < \sqrt{2}$.

Side note here, but if those smarter than I can clarify: would $|i|$ be $1$, $-1$ or $i$, where $i$ represents $\sqrt{-1}$? Because, then I could write $\sqrt{i^2}$ --> $\sqrt{-1}$ --> $i$, but if the absolute value also represents distance from 0, then $i$ is one unit away from 0 in the complex direction, so... Something to chew on.

Cheers!

Comment: The definition of the modulus of a complex number is just distance from the origin so in fact $|i| = 1$.

Comment: @OsamaGhani So then the definition of absolute value is the square root of the sum of the squares of the real and imaginary parts of a number. $|z = \text{a}+\text{b}i| = \sqrt{\text{a}^2 + \text{b}^2}$.

Comment: Exactly. However note that this means that $0 \leq x^2 \leq 2$ corresponds to $|x| \leq \sqrt{2}$ for real $x$ only. Otherwise the former inequality describes a line segment in the complex plane but the latter describes a disk.

Comment: To expand on Osama ghani's comment. $0\le x^2 \le 2$ implies $x$ must be real. $|x|\le \sqrt 2$ does not. So by the mere statement of the original post, we can assume it is understand that $x$ is real.

Comment: Sorry, but, how can you say that $|i|=\sqrt{i^2}=i$ when all that is true is $|x|=x$ for real $x\geq0$? (From WiKi) Since the complex numbers are not ordered, the definition given at the top for the real absolute value cannot be directly applied to complex numbers. However the geometric interpretation of the absolute value of a real number as its distance from 0 can be generalised. The absolute value of a complex number is defined by the Euclidean distance of its corresponding point in the complex plane from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by fleablood, $x$ must be a real number here.

By definition, $|x|$ of a real number $x$ is the **non-negative** value of $x$ without regard to its sign. So, as fleablood already said, $x$ is already understood to be an element of the set $\mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\}$. Obviously, $0 \leq x^2 \leq 2$ implies $0 \leq |x| \leq \sqrt{2}$. On the other hand, if we have that $|x| \leq \sqrt{2}$, then 
$|x|^2 \leq 2$. But $|x|^2=x^2$ (for real $x$) and $|x| \geq 0$ (by definition), and thus $0 \leq x^2 \leq 2$.

Here, it is worth to note that we can replace $<$ by $\leq$, but not $\leq$ with $<$.

Now, to get from the inequality $0 < |x| < \sqrt{2}$ to $0 < x^2 < 2$ (noting $|x| \geq 0$), we must *insist* that $|x| > 0$ since $x^2 \geq 0$ for real $x$ (too!).